# Подскажите, что это за шрифт?

Tags: шрифты, вёрстка, css, дизайн

Очень интересно название данного шрифта, который на изображении.
Сама ссылка: uplab.ru/i/logo.png

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что не относится к программированию.

Answer (score 1):

http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82+%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE&lr=213